# jQuery dynamic scrollbar as data is appended

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

im developing an interface of a chat tool and badly need your help. so my chat tool has a custom vertical scrollbar, im using [niceScroll](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/demo.html) and i've figured it has some minor issues when it comes to dynamic data being appended, in this case, when a user chats with the agent and the list goes long. Im having problems with this scrollbar since :

1. it will be disabled at first until it reaches a certain height and then the scroll bar is displayed.
2. the scrollbar doesnt know if a chat is appended so it doesnt automatically adjust the height.

im looking for a workaround, or a vertical scroll plugin that can solve this.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

[Jscrollpane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com) is a very good plugin (in my opinion) for custom scrollbars.

If you look at [this example](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/dynamic_content.html), I believe it's exactly what you need.

This [ajax example](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ajax.html) might also be useful to you!